# Is there a term to describe the relationship between both of my brothers in law?

Tags: kinship-terms

Is there an easier way of describing the relationship of my spouses brother to my sisters spouse?

*I am Rob, my wife is Sophie and her brother is Will. My sister is Rebecca and her husband is Tom. What is Toms relationship (if any) to Will other than his "brother in laws brother in law"?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a bit confusing (to me), but according to the title, *co-brother-in-law* (noun) is what you're looking for.

> [**Co-brother-in-law**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-brother-in-law):
>
> (Uncommon) One's wife's sister's husband; or more generally one's spouse's brother-in-law, the brother of one spouse in relation to the siblings of the other spouse. **[Wikitionary]**

Co-brothers-in-law: Men who marry sisters.